# title of a marker of google map marker API

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I try to change the color of part of the title, but look like the title option does not take html format. How can I make it work?

Thank you

```
var testtitle = '<font color="green">This is some text!</font> another text';   

var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
position: location,
title: testtitle,
map: map
});
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

you must use InfoWindow object

see this doc [google map api](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/infowindow-simple)

```
var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    content: "<span>any html goes here</span>"
});

var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: myLatlng,
    map: map,
    title: 'Uluru (Ayers Rock)'
});

google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
  infowindow.open(map,marker);
});
```

Comment: That require me for a click on the pin and that used to display a full data. I want a title on hover. That is why I use google marker.

Comment: use mouseover event google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'mouseover', function() { //your code

Comment: I got what you meant, but as I said that I use info window for a full data, not just the title. On the hover, I want to see a quick look of my data, just the title with html format.

Comment: Marker title is just string property of the Marker object - and it will not be never rendered as html

Comment: so I suggest to use 2 InfoWindow objects in your case - 1 for "full data" and 2nd - for html title

Comment: Great alternative idea. However, there is a problem with this strategy. I have to click on the x button to close that box instead of moving the mouse away from the pin to close that box. In my case I have hundreds of pin. It is not a good idea to have a quick look on the data since I have to click x to close every pin data when I hover it. If I didnt click x to close the box. Those box would appear everywhere and block my view.

Answer (score 2):

A "title" is a tooltip that is automatically created for the [google.maps.Marker](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Marker) object.  It doesn't support HTML markup.  If you want to create one that is different from the default, you can, but it would be custom.

See [this post](http://googlemapapitutorial.com/customizedtooltip.jsp) for one custom tool tip option (a [google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=google+maps+api+v3+tooltip) found 2 posts describing them).