# How to Construct HTML in form of a String for this

Tags: jquery

I am trying to change the title of the marker style

This is the HTML i am constructing and passing

But its not applying style

Could you please let em know how to resolve this

```
function createMarker(latlng, html) {
      var  tooltiponclcik = 'Company Name :  1  , <br> ' + 'Sales Off Name :  2  , <br>' + 'Warehouse Name :  3 ';     
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: latlng,
        map: map,
        zIndex: Math.round(latlng.lat() * -100000) << 5,
        title:tooltiponclcik
    });
}
```

The title can be only of a Straight text , so can i construct that ??
This is my fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/6wp7enot/16/

Comment: See if this is related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19279199/title-of-a-marker-of-google-map-marker-api

Comment: Not sure what you mean by `change the title of the marker style ` either....doesn't really make sense. If you want more robust title use `markerWithLabel` plugin.